# Pyqtgraph's PlotWidget doesn't show correctly

Tags: python, plot, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I've been trying to embed a graph into my application using pyqtgraph's PlotWidget. It seemed simple enough while following [this tutorial](https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/embed-pyqtgraph-custom-widgets-qt-app/). I have managed to show a graph well enough, the problem is that the graph looks broken. Here is an image of the most simple app I could make to show the problem:

[Bugged graph app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEIeo.png)

I used the following code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QApplication)
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget
from PyQt5 import uic
import sys

class UI(QMainWindow):
            
    def __init__(self):
        super(UI, self).__init__()
        
        # Load the ui file
        uic.loadUi("test.ui", self)
        
        self.GraphWidget = self.findChild(PlotWidget,"GraphWidget")

        self.GraphWidget.showGrid(x=True, y=True)
        
        # Show The App
        self.show()

            
            
# Initialize The App
def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    UIWindow = UI()
    app.exec_()
      
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

The steps I followed in Qt Designer were:

1. Add QWidget to the main window
2. Promote it to PlotWidget, setting the header file to pyqtgraph
3. Save test.ui file

When I tried embedding the graph into my program, the same bug appeared. That's why I have made this simple example to showcase it.

Some notes about my setup:

- I'm using windows 11 (perhaps it's this, but I can't test it in another computer).
- Python version 3.9.7
- Qt version 5.9.7
- Pyqtgraph version 0.11.0
- I'm using Anaconda, and to test this I created a clean environment and installed just the necessary packages.

I would appreciate any help with this.

**EDIT**

The test.ui file contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>480</width>
    <height>419</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="PlotWidget" name="GraphWidget" native="true"/>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>PlotWidget</class>
   <extends>QWidget</extends>
   <header>pyqtgraph</header>
   <container>1</container>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: what's in test.ui file

Comment: Do you perhaps have two monitors with different scaling factors? It may be the same as [PyQtGraph issue #756](https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/issues/756#issuecomment-610288624)

Comment: @titusjan you are absolutely right! That is the problem. Thank you so much for identifying the issue and pointing me to the other thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @titusjan pointed out, I do have two monitors with different scaling factors. Running the program with the same scaling factors or with just one monitor fixed the problem.

There also are some workarounds in the [issue thread](https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/issues/756#issuecomment-610288624) @titusjan provided.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with external monitors, but

```
QApplication.setAttribute(Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling)
```

***before***

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
```

solved them...